# How is this sound created?

Tags: sound-effects, synthesizer, replication

I've been wondering how to create the following sound (by using a synth) (which wave etc..)

Starts at 0:19

..As well as the effect done on the vocal track at 0:07-0:09  (same song)

The stuttering sound I used to create by using granular synthesis, is there any big difference to a trancegate? But what I actually wanted to know is how to create the effect right after the "stuttering", this down and up pitch shift..

Answer (score 1):

I mainly hear a sawtooth (supersaw like) wave and when the melody is on the lower tones I hear a triangle wave in the sound. There is probably a unison used in the sound.

The effect you hear is a trancegate; this effect creates a stuttery effect. 
Check this [trancegate tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpS2FNGnMds) to see how a trancegate is created.

**Edit**

A trancegate or rhythmic gate/step-sequenced gate is an effect that chops up long and sustained sounds to create small note-like segments that are in sync with the tempo of your production. You will be using a trancegate mostly on string and pad sounds since the sound gets chopped up. This chopped effect is created by lowering and raising the volume envelope (like the shape of a square wave) from 0% to 100% directly in a rhythmic manner. With effect plugins for trancegates you can make automation clips to manipulate the tempo sync to the beat. For example switching from 1/16 to 1/32 to 1/8. This enables you to create complex rhythmic sounds.

Comment: hi Hkidd, your trancegate tutorial link is nice, but what if the link goes down? Can you explain (in short) what a trancegate is and how it can be done?

Comment: Thanks so far! :D The stuttering sound I used to create by using granular synthesis, is there any big difference to a trancegate?
But what I actually wanted to know is how to create the effect right after the "stuttering" :D This down and up pitch shift..

Comment: I've added my definition of a trancegate

Comment: user13324 you can achieve that effect, like you say, by a down and up pitch shift. Take for example a sampler plugin, load a vocal sample (like in the song), set how many semitones the pitch shift will follow and then automate a pitch shift that goes from for example 100% to 45% (not all the way down).